# Importing Active Directory Module from a server

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is there a way to import Active Directory Module to a Windows 7 workstation from a server using Power Shell?  We have server 2008 and 2012.

The reason is that, we don't want install Active Directory Module on all of our workstations.

Comment: Set up a constrained endpoint on a server with the Module installed, have people connect to that

Comment: Thank you, I'm kind of new to powershell, can you tell me how I would do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to the AD-Server via `New-PSSession Hostname -name ModuleSession` and do a `Import-PSSession -Name ModuleSession` to import all modules of that session. But keep in mind that you need to have administrative right to do that. If you only want to get some info about you ad-objects, adsi would be the better way (only user permissions needed).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that